# Regex - match starting with 'XXX' up to next occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey my goal is to separate something like

```
FOO 1
 UP 2.0
 DOWN 33
 Blubber 33@11 44@55
FOO 2
 ZZZ 1.0
 X 3
 Blubber 1@4 4@5 6@22
FOO 4
 ABC D
 Blubber 33@11 44@55
```

into each block of FOO up to the next FOO:

```
FOO 1
 UP 2.0
 DOWN 33
 Blubber 33@11 44@55
```

and as second result

```
FOO 2
 ZZZ 1.0
 X 3
 Blubber 1@4 4@5 6@22
```

and so on..

my attempt was to get the Answers of [Regex - match up to next match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639421/regex-match-up-to-next-match) working for me but do not really understand how to.
Must i enclose FOO in braces? `(FOO)` ?
I Hope someone can help me out of the forest...
Sunny greetings Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` with positive lookahead should work:

```
var arr = str.split(/(?=FOO\s\d+)/);
```

Demo (check the console): http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/6pxuz/

Comment: thanks! if I understand it right it checks up from FOO up to the last number?

Comment: ok i think i have understood it: `(?=xxx)` loos for xxx and just returns the position. so `FOO\s\d+` looks for FOO followed by a blank and a number. Is there a alternative way to get this done with `.match` just out of interest?

Comment: @StefanKrüger: you could try `.match(/[\s\S]+?(?=FOO\s\d+)/)`.

Comment: hm thats just returns the first match... it works with split - ist fine ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: forgot the `/g` modifier, `.match(/[\s\S]+?(?=FOO\s\d+)/g)`